# why the number of relations seem to be smaller than the number of functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I may ask a stupid question:

let's say I have 2 sets. A has a number of elements. $B$ has $b$ number of elements. The number of relation from $A$ to $B$ is $|A×B|$ $=$ $|A|×|B|= a × b$. The number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$ = $b^a$.

Usually, $b^a$ > $b*a$. like $2^3$ > $2*3$. But functions have stricter rules than relations. Should it have less number of functions than relations? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Every function is a relation so the number of functions is less than or equal to the number of relations.  You seem to have confused the formula for the number of possible relations.  A relation is a subset of the cartesian product $A\times B$.  The set of relations then is $\mathcal{P}(A\times B)$ and is of size $2^{a\cdot b}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum number of relations?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071894/maximum-number-of-relations)

Answer (score 3):

Your first calculation counts the number of ordered pairs, not the number of relations. A relation is a subset of the Cartesian product. So the number of relations is the cardinality of the power set of $A\times B$, in your case $2^{ab}$.

Comment: (And indeed $2^{ab}=(2^b)^a> b^a$ because $2^b>b$. I'm assuming $a,b$ are finite and positive given the example in your post, but this all works out for transfinite cardinals too.)